# Getting default Android attr within custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a Custom EditText the extends from EditText. I would like to get the default attr `android:selectAllOnFocus` when the user set it to the Custom EditText.

I code below in the constructor

```
boolean selecteAllOnFocus = false;
selectAllOnFocus = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue("android", "selectAllOnFocus", selectAllOnFocus);
```

It is not getting the value. Is there anything I miss?

Comment: Have you tried with full url/path namespace? Like this `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`.

Comment: Yes, it's there alrady in the xml... `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the full namespace

```
boolean selecteAllOnFocus = false;
boolean value = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "selectAllOnFocus", selectAllOnFocus)
```